# Directly Enable Permission Like Location

Tags: java, android

I can implement Runtime permission where a dialog appears to the user to allow the permission or deny the permission. But I want The permission will be enabled or allowed in the background without asking the User. Is it possible? is it possible then how to do it? Please explain in Java (Android studio).

Answer (score 1):

> in the background without asking the User. Is it possible?

no.

this defeats the point of the permission model - if any random app could just get your location (or any other sensitive permission) without requesting for it, why would apps even bother to implement runtime permissions ?

Comment: So, there has no such method to make it automatically enable without asking the user on the above API 23? But it was In blow API 23, I think. is there any clarification of it from you?

Comment: the permission model was added in to avoid automatically granting permissions, exactly like my answer says, it isn't possible on newer android devices.